# Execute very long-running tasks using Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-run

I have been using Google CLoud for a few weeks now and I am facing a big problem for my limited GCP knowledge.

I have a python project whos goal is to "scrape" datas from a website using it's API. My project run a few tens of thousands of requests during executions and it can take very long (few hours, maybe more)

I have 4 python scripts in my project and **it's all orchestrated by a bash script**.

**The execution is as follow :**

- The first script check a CSV file with all the instructions for the requests, and exeute the requests, save all the results from the requests in CSV files
- Second script check the previously created CSV files and recreate an other CSV instruction file
- The first script run again but with the new instructions and again save results in CSV files
- Second script checks again and do the same again ...
- ... and so on a few times
- Third script cleans the datas, delete duplicates and create an unique CSV file
- Fourth script upload the final CSV file to bucket storage

Now I want to get ride of that bash script and I would like to automatize execution of thos scripts approx. once a week.

The problem here is the execution time. Here is what I already tested :

**Google App Engine** : The timeout of a request on GAE is limited to 10 minutes, and my functions can run for few hours. GAE is not usable here.

**Google Compute Engine** : My scripts will run max. 10-15 hours a week, keeping a compute engine up during all that time would be too pricey.

What could I do to automatize the execution of my scripts in a cloud environment ? What could be solutions I didn't though about, without changing my code ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you run in parallel all the instructions?

Comment: Sadly no, they must be excuted one after the other

Comment: It's sad for the speed, but a serverless solution is possible, need more monitoring but less VM management.

Comment: Cloud Build comes to mind, but it implies building a container with the python script of each step, and re-writing the orchestrating script in a yaml like cloud build likes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to accomplish this without the need to get rid of the existing bash script that orchestrates everything would be:

1. Include the bash script on the [startup script for the instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript).
2. At the end of the bash script, include a `shutdown` command.
3. Schedule the starting of the instance using [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth). You'll have to make an authenticated call to the GCE API to [start the existing instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/start).

With that, your instance will start on a schedule, it will run the startup script (that will be your existing orchestrating script), and it will shut down once it's finished.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like a really good way to do it ! Does the startup script run each time you start the instance or just when you create it ? I need a pretty powerfull instance with at least 32GB RAM, will I be charged if the instance is shutdown ?

Comment: Yes, the startup script will run every time you start the instance. The charges for CPU and memory will stop [if the instance is `Terminated` (stopped)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing#instanceuptime). Persistent disks, static IPs, and other permanent resources will still accrue charges. You can check the pricing page for more details: https://cloud.google.com/compute/all-pricing

Comment: Make sure to write proper bash scripts with error checking and write a `trap` in bash to also shutdown the VM if the script fails along the way.